# Event tracking with GUID in value field

Tags: matomo, piwiktracker

Does the value have to be numeric, I am trying to store unique Ids (strings) in the value field, but when I look at the reports only a zero (0) value is being stored.

here is example of issue:

```
 "type": "event",
        "eventCategory": "Online-Ordering-Menu",
        "eventAction": "ItemAddToCart",
        "eventName": "ItemId",
        "eventValue": 0  -- I want this be value of the Item which is type GUID structure '4eb3f8ba-6bf2-414b-8146-b75bce6a283f'
```

is it possible to store that value?

After Reading through the documentation and not rushing a found the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The event value has to be numeric, but you should be able to store what you want by storing the data in the `eventName`.

> It will log an event with an event category (Videos, Music, Games…), an event action (Play, Pause, Duration, Add Playlist, Downloaded, Clicked…), and an optional event name and optional numeric value.
>
> from https://matomo.org/docs/event-tracking/#tracking-events